# GraphQL error: variable price of type Float is used in position expecting float8

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, vue-apollo, hasura

I get an error while sending data from Apollo to Hasura GraphQL:

> Error: GraphQL error: variable price of type Float is used in position
>   expecting float8

This is my code in nuxt js

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const insert = gql`
mutation insert_test_float($price:Float){
  insert_test_float(objects: {price: $price}) {
    affected_rows
  }
}

save() {
  const price =  this.frm.price
  this.$apollo
    .mutate({
      mutation: insert, //require('~/apollo/mutations/test'),
      variables: {
        price: this.frm.price
      }
    })
    .then((rs) => {
      console.log(rs)
    })
    .catch((er) => {
      console.log(er)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `float8` as your variable type instead of `Float` as the error indicates.